# How can I mix PHP variables with SELECT data in a MySQL INSERT query?

Tags: php, mysql, select, join, insert

I have a DB with `table1 (id, name_id, value)` and `table2 (id, name, other)`

then I have some data

```
$name = 'a name';
$value = 'a value';
```

I want to use the value `$name` as `table2.name` to get `table2.id` and insert it into `table1` as `table1.name_id` but then I also want to insert `$value` into `table1`.

when doing a `SELECT` I could use `JOIN`, but the only thing I've found for `INSERT` is to use a `SELECT` query instead of `VALUES`

However, I want to use a value from `table2` (`id`) as well as insert `$value` but the `SELECT` method seems to only copy data from one table (`table2`) to another

Edit: pseudo SQL

```
<pre>INSERT INTO `table1` (`name_id`, `value`)
VALUES ((`table2`.`id` WHERE `table2`.`name` = $name), $value)</pre>
```

Comment: Please give an example in pseudo SQL because I cannot follow what you are trying to say here at all

Comment: updated it, but I think juergen (and Kevin's, although I don't use PDO) are what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into table1 (name_id, other)
select id, 'just some static data or data from a variable'
from table2
where name = '$name'
```

I inserted the variable for better readability. But I recommend using *Prepared Statements* instead.

Comment: sorry, I just updated the question. the method you posted is the one I've found, but how could I add another bit of data (which isn't in `table2` into a `table1` column?

Comment: ah. I am using prepared statements as well, so would it be `select id, ?` and then I would just bind params as usual?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work (assuming PDO since you didn't specify):

```
$preparedStmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 (name_id,value)
    SELECT id, :value FROM table2 WHERE name=:name");
$preparedStmt->execute(array('name'=>$name,'value'=>$value));
```